# VC dimension of monotone disjunctions of length k over n variables?

Tags: learning-theory, vc-dimension

There are of course $n \choose k$ monotone disjunctions which bounds the VC dimension at $\log_2 {n \choose k}$. I'm wondering if this is bound at $k \log_2 n$? (Possibly follows from combinatorial identities).

More generally I'm looking at the claim in [An algorithmic theory of learning: Robust concepts and random projection](http://rd.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10994-006-6265-7#/page-1): "Further, it is NP-hard to learn a disjunction of $k$ variables as a disjunction of few than $k \log n$ variable." The author states this without proof; I'm assuming it's well-known or obvious but am trying to figure out why or where it is proved.

Comment: You mention $n \log k$ and $k \log n$ - was one of them a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  This bound follows by a little bit of straightforward manipulation:

$${n \choose k} = {n \times (n-1) \times \dots \times (n-k+1) \over k!} \le {n \times n \times \dots \times n \over 1} = n^k.$$

Now taking the logarithm of both sides, we see that

$$ \lg {n \choose k} \le \lg(n^k) = k \lg n.$$

The bound can also be derived from [bounds listed in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Bounds_and_asymptotic_formulas): it follows from the fact that ${n \choose k} \le n^k/k!$.  Check out Wikipedia in the future -- it's often helpful!

Comment: Thanks, yeah it was easy. I don't see the full claim following like I thought it would; so posted question on the full claim [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/50877/27338).

Comment: I see why I was confused...  this gives an upper bound, I needed lower ... :/

Comment: @djechlin,  You can obtain an asymptotic lower bound from inequalities listed on that same Wikipedia page.